# QlikView/SQL - If statement w/ IsNull

Tags: sql, qlikview

The logic for the problem is that I am attempting to resolve an issue where a certain field will return a null value and I would like to auto-generate a value for this field to that of another similar value given that its other relevant fields are the same.

Example (for both results):

*GradYear: 2018 ----
StudentName: Jake ----
*SchoolNumber: 54 ----
*StateCode: NA11 ----
CountyCode: MA02 ----
*SchoolName: Hillsburn ----

*GradYear: 2018 ----
StudentName: Sarah ----
*SchoolNumber: 54 ----
*StateCode: NA11 ----
CountyCode: NULL ----
*SchoolName: Hillsburn ----

As seen above, the CountCody for Sarah returns a null value. I am attempting to make it so that it will automatically fill the value for CountyCode, if the other similar values are the same between Students. (The necessary similar values being shown with a '*'.) 
Also, I am attempting to solve this without using the "Previous" feature or hard-coded information so that it may be accomplished with any data.

My original attempt was to use a simple if/IsNull statement along with a Peek feature but the values persisted at returning a null value.

if((isnull(CountyCode)), Peek(CountyCode), CountyCode)  as CountyCode

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: just to confirm - if `Country Code` is null then it should be updated to contain any value (which is not null obviously) from `Country Code` field in general?

Comment: It should be updated to a value that is aligned with other students who share the same exact fields (GradYear, StateCode, SchoolNumber, & SchoolName).

Answer (score 1):

I would use `applymap` for this.

lets says the `SchoolNumber` is unique to `CountyCode`.

so first lets load our mapping table:

```
    CountyCode_Map:
    mapping load distinct SchoolNumber, CountyCode 
    from Data.qvd (qvd) where len(CountyCode)>0;
```

Now when loading you data use this for `CountyCode`:

```
applymap('CountyCode_Map',SchoolNumber) as CountyCode
```

in case that `SchoolNumber` is not unique to `CountyCode` you can use any other field or a concatenation of fields.

for more info on `applymap` : [link](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2018/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/MappingFunctions/ApplyMap.htm)